# How to update the page regularly in jsf2.0?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

My JSF 2.0 page is contains some data, which is dynamic hence needs automatic refresh in some predefined time interval(say every 10 seconds). 
I am using PrimeFaces 3.5 as a powerful component suite. Below is the managed bean-

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public Monitor implements Serializable {

    //max,min,avg,stdDev,reason are caluclated based on some dynamic data
    private int max;
    private int min;
    private double avg;
    private double stdDev;
    private String reason;

    public int getMax() {
            //Here before returning I am calling some methods to get the max from dynamic data
        return max;
    }

    public int getMin() {
            //Here before returning I am calling some methods to get the min from dynamic data
        return min;
    }

    public double getAvg() {
            //Here before returning I am calling some methods to get the avg from dynamic data
        return avg;
    }

    public String getReason() {
            //Here before returning I am calling some methods to get the reason from dynamic data
        return reason;
    }

    public double getStdDev() {
            //Here before returning I am calling some methods to get the stdDev from dynamic data
        return stdDev;
    }

    public void setMax(int max) {
        this.max = max;
    }

    public void setMin(int min) {
        this.min = min;
    }

    public void setAvg(double avg) {
        this.avg = avg;
    }

    public void setStdDev(double stdDev) {
        this.stdDev = stdDev;
    }

    public void setReason(String reason) {
        this.reason = reason;
    }
}
```

I haven't finalize the layout till now however i would be like this-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <p:panel>
            <h:outputLabel value="#{monitor.min}" />
            <h:outputLabel value="#{monitor.max}" />
            <h:outputLabel value="#{monitor.avg}" />
            <h:outputLabel value="#{monitor.stdDev}" />
            <h:outputLabel value="#{monitor.reason}" />
        </p:panel>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

How can I update the page regularly in JSF 2.0?

Comment: You try **Poll** :http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/poll.jsf

Comment: @RongNK: Can i have conditional refresh? I mean let say when avg is more than 50. I want to stop this refresh process and simply want to show some other page.

Comment: You can, poll can stop and start.

Comment: Example is described here http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10480#p37755. @RongNK, you can probably add with a answer to make this question complete.

Comment: ok, i will post as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[Poll](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/poll.jsf)** to auto refresh your page, **Poll** can start stop via javascript:
for example, poll will stop when count(bean variable) >=10:
You can use stop like @Ravi [post](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10480#p37755), my example demo you can start stop(via: pol.stop() and pol.start()).

Facelets:

```
<h:form id="form">  
            <p:panel id="pntest">
              // content here
            </p:panel>
            <h:outputText id="txt_count" value="#{tabview.count}" />
            <p:poll interval="1" listener="#{tabview.increment}" update="txt_count" widgetVar="pol" oncomplete="test(xhr, status, args);"/>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                //<![CDATA[
                function test(xhr, status, args){
                    if(args.sotest >= 10){
                        pol.stop();
                    }else{
                       location.reload(); // refresh page                        
                     }
                }
                //]]>
            </script>
        </h:form>
```

Bean:

```
     private int count = 0;
        public void increment() {
                count++;
                RequestContext reqCtx = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
                reqCtx.addCallbackParam("sotest", count);
                //1. update by using PrimeFaces specific API, use [RequestContext#update()][3].
                RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("form:pntest");
                //2. update by using standard JSF API, add the client ID to [PartialViewContext#getRenderIds()][4].             

FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds().add("form:pntest");
            }

            public int getCount() {
                return this.count;
            }

            public void setCount(int count) {
                this.count = count;
            }
```

Comment: I got it. One more question. Can i use poll with `p:panelGrid` ? I mean can i refresh the entire `p:panelGrid` using `p:poll`?

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can update in panel from backing bean via two approachs(you choose one between two approachs).